# Warning messages like error messages in VSCode with c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Warning messages such as "Variable 'e' is declared but never used" may not allow the solution to compile, in visual studio code with c#. Force developers to create cleaner code. It's possible?

Comment: From what I remember there is an option called "Treat warnings as errors" or something like this in VS.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#treatwarningsaserrors

Comment: could this be just for visual studio ?. I am searching for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It's a C# compiler option so it applies to both studio and code. You can set it in your .csproj file using the XML example in that section I linked.

Comment: To apply it to all projects, you should be able to add it to one of the shared MSBuild files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022

Comment: excellent, there I could configure it. Thank you very much for your time!